# What's the difference between OO人もいる vs OO人がいる?

Tags: grammar, particle-も

Recently I came across some lines and could not really understand what the "も" is doing in them.

Example:

> 私にクラスに鈴木さんという名の生徒が５人[も]{L}いるので驚いた。

vs

> 私にクラスに鈴木さんという名の生徒が５人[が]{L}いるので驚いた。

Thinking about "も" here as "even" or "also" in these examples don't really make sense to me here and I read in another post that it has a total affirmation usage but I can't quite grasp it.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence:

> 私<s>に</s>**の**クラスに鈴木さんという名の生徒**が**５人**が**いるので驚いた。

is not correct. You don't use two が's that way. You'd instead say:

> 私のクラスに鈴木さんという名の生徒**が**５人いるので驚いた。

"Numeral + counter", such as ５人, ２個, ３回 etc., can function adverbially. You'd use it like this:

> 生徒がいる。 There're students. → 生徒が**５人**いる。 There're five students.
> りんごを食べる。 I eat apples. → りんごを**３個**食べる。 I eat three apples.
> 山田さんに会った。 I met Yamada-san. → 山田さんに**３回**会った。 I met Yamada-san three times.

---

も, used after a numeral and counter, means "as many as" "as much as". You'd use it this way:

> 生徒が５人**も**いる。 There're as many as five students.
> りんごを３個**も**食べる。 I eat as many as three apples.
> 山田さんに３回**も**会った。 I met Yamada-san as many as three times.

So your first sentence:

私のクラスに鈴木さんという名の生徒が５人**も**いるので驚いた。

means "I was surprised because there were **as many as** five students named Suzuki in my class."

Comment: Ah, thank you for all the explanations! As many as/ as much as is such a simple way to think of that yet when I looked up that usage most translations just omitted it.